# Logical equivalences for $P \implies Q$ and $\neg Q \implies \neg P$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is probably quite a basic question, but it's something I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

I came across a proof which employed the following strategy

The goal was to prove

$$P \implies Q$$

And the strategy used was to prove the following instead:

$$\neg Q \implies \neg P$$

If possible, could someone provide some intuition as to why these two statements would be equivalent?

Comment: Why not consider some concrete examples?

Comment: IMHO the best way to get an intuitive feeling for this kind of thing is to look at examples.  "If you live in London then you live in the UK" and "if you don't live in the UK then you don't live in London" are really just two ways of stating the same fact.  Make up your own examples too!

Comment: This is called the contrapositive. The Wikipedia page has an intuitive explanation, though a few examples should clear this up for you.

Comment: @David Ah okay I see, I think I understand it better if I draw a Venn Diagram - P should be contained in Q?

Comment: Mmm... I guess... if it works for you.  Wouldn't go that way myself, doubt that it would give me any intuitive understanding.

Comment: Concrete examples. Good idea. "If I am a duck, I like to eat snails" lets take that for granted.  Now if I don't like to eat snails am I duck, or not, or can't we tell?  Well, if a I *were* a duck I *would* like to eat snails.  But I don't.  So I guess I can't be a duck, can I.  So if I don't like to eat snails then I am not a duck.  Okay, that was one way.  Going the other way is pretty much the same.  Let's take "If I don't like snails I can't be a duck" as given. Now suppose I'm a duck, what can we say about my liking snails? Well, if I didn't like them I *wouldn't* be a duck... but I am...

Comment: Or... If I am a twin, then I like sugar => twins can't *not* like sugar.  So if I *don't* like sugar... I can't be a twin.  Contrarywise:  If you don't like sugar you can't be a twin=>sugar dis-likers cant be twins.  So if I *am* a twin and can't be a sugar disliker.  So if I am a twin I must like sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P \implies Q$ means whenever you have $P$ you will have $Q$.

That means if you have $P$ then $\lnot Q$ is impossible.

That means if you *do* have $\lnot Q$, it isn't possible that you had $P$ (because then you *would* have had $Q$).

That means if you  have $\lnot Q$ then you will have $\lnot P$.

That means $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$.

... So if "$P \implies Q$" is true it is also true that "$\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$".

====

Likewise $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$ means whenever $Q$ is false then $P$ is false.

So if you have $P$ is true it isn't possible that you had $Q$ is false (because if $Q$ is false $P$ *wouldn't* be true.)

So if somehow you had $P$ is true and it isn't possible that $Q$ is false, it must be that $Q$ is true.

So if you did have $P$ is true it must follow that $Q$ is true.

So $P \implies Q$.

... So if "$\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$" is true it will follow that "$P \implies Q$" is true.

====

So the two statements $P\implies Q$ and $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$ can only be true if the other one is true, and if one is false the other can't be true and if one is true the other must also be true, these two statements are always true or false under the exact same circumstances.

In other words... they are equivalent statements.

Comment: Wow, this really cleared things up for me! Thank you for going through it using first principles, it becomes so much clearer! (:

Answer (score 2):

In classical logic this boils down to the definition of $\implies$. You can then check this equivalence by testing all possible combinations of truth values for $P$ and $Q$. This principle is called [contraposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

In intuitionistic logic, you only get that $P\implies Q$ implies $\lnot Q\implies \lnot P$, but not the converse.

Contraposition is often a convenient way of starting a proof, in particular if you don't know where you want to go with your proof. But *many* such proofs can be in fact reformulated to be direct proofs.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ implies $Q$, then $\lnot Q$ cannot imply $P$; because that would in turn imply $Q$ (a contradiction).   So therefore must $\lnot Q$ imply $\lnot P$.

That is: $P\to Q$ entails that $\lnot Q\to\lnot P$.

---

Likewise if $\lnot Q$ implies $\lnot P$, then $P$ cannot imply $\lnot Q$; because that would in turn imply $\lnot P$ (a contradiction).   So therefore must $P$ imply $\lnot\lnot Q$.

In classical logic, that double negation can be eliminated, so we can say $\lnot Q\to\lnot P$ entails $P\to Q$.